# Python 2 cgi field storage post variable encoding

Tags: python, encoding, cgi

I can't get this piece of information anywhere.

Does anyone know what the encoding of a string retrieved via a python cgi fieldstorage object is?

For example, I have this html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<body>
    <form id="mainForm" method="post" action="./uploadArticle.py">
        <input type="text" name="articletitle" /></br>
        <textarea name="articlebody" rows="50" cols="100"/></textarea></br>
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

That I process through this python file with apache :

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
title = form["articletitle"].value
content = form["articlebody"].value
```

Will title and content be utf8 encoded strings?

Answer (score 0):

The question shows a little bit of confusion about what encoding is.

Data received over the internet is just bytes. Python has no way of knowing what "encoding" it is; that's entirely dependent on how it was produced.

In Python 3, that data will be a bytestring; in Python 2, it will be a string, but neither of these have an intrinsic encoding.

If you do know the source encoding you can decode it to a unicode string; utf-8 is a good guess, and will do the right thing in most circumstances, but it can be wrong.

Comment: I see. Let's say i want to decode the title variable, which contains raw bytes, into a readable string. The encoding I would use depends on the way the string was encoding "by the form" ?

Comment: Well, not the form but the computer on which the data was entered, but yes. As I say though, utf-8 is usually a fairly safe guess.